# Xcode7.3.1 - Linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, xcode7

I have been getting this error when I open a project in Xcode 7.3.1. Can anyone please tell me what is the exact problem. I have attached the error Image 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So many different problems for the same error message.(`Linker command failed with exit code 1`)

**1)** if you had two same constants in different classes then also this issue happens.

**2)** if you have accidently imported a `.m` file instead of `.h` file in an implementation file.

3) This error can also be occurred if you have imported two different versions of same library ,in this case just remove the older version and keep only one version.

4) Adding the "`other linker flags`" in "`Project`" and not in "`Targets`". So, you move it to "`Targets`", it shouldn't be in "`Project`".

5) Check it out in **project->target->build settings-> search enable bitcode->set NO** in DEBUG

check out this .. if it's OK then once do like following.

**Menu > Product > Clean** ... then Run the project

Hope it helps you.. :)

Comment: Hi I dont know it happens almost everytime it is because the project developed before was in lower versions of Xcode. I tried solving using your solution but since am new to xcode couldnt exactly figure out the problem. So if you could help me more would be appreciated :D

Comment: check out above all the possibilities.. and then Menu>product>clean... then run...... after this,if u r facing with same issue... then just do new project and copy paste all the files